# Converting md5 to two long variables in Java

Tags: java, hash, md5, long-integer

I'm trying to hash some values and use the hashed value as an index in my database. Not having collisions is very important, which is why I'm going with md5. Having 128 bits, gives me more than the space I need to not worry about collisions (I know that md5 is not collision safe).

Anyways, how can I store the result of the md5 in a database and so that I can index it and retrieve it quickly? I was thinking of having two Long variables where one would hold the value of the first 64 bits and the other the second 64 bits and use both keys as an index on my database. But I need a fast way for doing this... what would be the fastest way ?

I don't think storing the md5 hashed value as a byte array will help much when I need indexing.

Comment: Storing it as a string? Varchar??

Comment: Wouldn't a sequence be good enough to generate unique numbers for a primary key ?

Comment: Wouldn't indexing as an int be faster than string or varchar?

Comment: @user1598390, I don't follow what you mean. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Roozbeh15 it seemed to me that the only reason you wanted the md5 for was to use it as a colission free value for a key. But maybe I got it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store it as a string (VARCHAR) and let your DB index that. This is the easiest solution, and you'll get the performance boost from the index.

Comment: Isn't indexing as int (or bigint) a lot faster than varchar? I was under the impression that it would be faster that way.

Comment: @Roozbeh15 It really depends on the kind of queries you make. If you want to do some sort of full-text search queries, indexing a string might not help that much (unless you use a full-text index or something like that). In your case, you are just doing exact match comparisons, so I don't see why there would be a huge performance difference between int and varchar indices.

Comment: maybe I'm going about this all wrong. I'm actually trying to do full-text search queries. What I want to do is hash the text strings into bigints and look them up that way.

Comment: So why not use a search engine, or the built-in free-text search functionality that some (most?) databases provide?

Comment: By "full-text search", I mean searching within a string for patterns. For example, finding "dog" in the string "catdogcat". On the other had, you are matching strings exactly, I believe (via the MD5 hash). Thus you can use a simple varchar index of the hash.